# Error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(HospitalFragment,Class<hospital_1>)

Tags: android

Error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(HospitalFragment,Class)

I want  HospitalFragment Class >>> (go to) >> Class hospital_1:

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr0Ey.jpg)

[image]

public class HospitalFragment extends Fragment {

public HospitalFragment() {
    }

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hospital, container, false);

    ImageButton hh1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.hh1);
    hh1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent showpic = new Intent( HospitalFragment.this,hospital_1.class);
        }
    });

    ImageButton hh2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.hh2);
    hh2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent showpic = new Intent(HospitalFragment.this, hospital_2.class);
            startActivity(showpic);
        }
    });


    ImageButton hh3= (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.h3);
    hh3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {goToURL("https://www.google.com");
        }
    });


    return view;
}


private void goToURL(String url) {
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
    startActivity(launchBrowser);
}
```

}

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but for any future posts—and for anyone else reading this—_please_ don't post code or error messages as screenshots. It's difficult to read, it's difficult for contributors to copy and paste (e.g., for testing, fixing code) and it prevents code from being indexed, thus making it hard for people with related problems to find. In this case, I realize that (most of?) the code, at least, is duplicated below as markdown, but for the most part the screenshots don't add much value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to the `Intent` constructor must be a `Context`, but your `HospitalFragment` class is *not* a `Context`.

The reason you often see code like `MyClass.this` as the first argument to the Intent constructor is that `Activity`s *are* `Context`s. So if your click listener were being set inside an Activity instead of a Fragment, your code would work just fine.

The good news is that all `View`s have a `getContext()` method, and all click listeners get a `View` argument passed to them. You can just retrieve the context from that!

So, replace this:

> ```
> ImageButton hh1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.hh1);
> hh1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View view) {
>         Intent showpic = new Intent( HospitalFragment.this,hospital_1.class);
>     }
> });
> ```

with this:

```
ImageButton hh1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.hh1);
hh1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent showpic = new Intent(view.getContext(), hospital_1.class);
    }
});
```

And do the same sort of thing for your other listeners as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
Intent showpic = new Intent(HospitalFragment.this, hospital_2.class);
```

using this for creating a intent.

```
Intent showpic = new Intent(v.getContext(), hospital_2.class);
```

whereas `v` is the View created by

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hospital, container, false);
```

i am not using it as `view` because inside of your `onClick()`, there is also a `View` of name `view`. `HosipitalFragment.this` is not a valid context that's its appears with red lines